# How to initialise my WPF app using MVVMLight?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, inversion-of-control, mvvm-light

I am building a WPF application using MVVM Light and having problems tying up my Views to my View Model. I have a view model in which I am passing in an Interface of IDataContext, which is basically passing in a datacontext.Then I have an View which I have inserted the following statement on top

```
DataContext="{Binding MyViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

In my ViewModelLocator I have added the following lines :

```
IoC.Register<IDataContext, MyDataContext>();
```

and

```
IoC.Register<MyViewModel>();
```

And after putting a break point in the constructor of the 'MyViewModel', the breakpoint gets hit. Is there something I am missing, please help???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you define a public getter for your viewModel in ViewModelLocator class as shown below?

```
    public MyViewModel MainViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MyViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

and then use the "MainViewModel" in the view binding as shown below

```
DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

What kind of behavior you see? Empty view window with no datacontext set? OR exception when displaying your view?

Comment: Thank so much, was just about to dump MVVM Light. It worked,it was the last piece of my puzzle

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this http://nileshgule.blogspot.com/2011/05/integrate-mvvmlight-toolkit-with-basic.html

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I am not looking for a way to integrate MVVM Light into my app. I have used MVVMlight templates to create my Project, View and ViewModel and the stuff to integrate MVVMlight is already implemented in these templates. I need help on how I can initialise my viewmodels as I have only seen Silverlight samples and not WPF. Any help???